# Pandas Pivot_Table index values shown but columns and counts do not show

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to do a simple pivot table and for some reason the columns and counts do not appear in the results.

Sample df (as Dict):

```
{'Date': {0: '2024-02-20',  1: '2024-02-18',  2: '2024-02-16',  3: '2024-02-01',  4: '2024-02-20',  5: '2024-01-21',  6: '2024-02-20',  7: '2024-01-21',  8: '2024-02-20',  9: '2024-02-20',  10: '2024-02-20'},
 'Status': {0: 'Won',  1: 'Credit Pulled',  2: 'Credit Pulled',  3: 'Credit Pulled',  4: 'Pre Credit Pull',  5: 'Credit Pulled',  6: 'Credit Pulled',  7: 'Won',  8: 'Awaiting Bank Account',  9: 'Credit Pulled',  10: 'Credit Pulled'}}
```

```
dfPivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df,index=['Date'],columns=['Status'],aggfunc="count")
```

Results: Only the date column is displayed in dfPivot.

Expectation (made in Excel):
[Excel Pivot Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zInuv.png)

I tried changing the "columns" to "values" and that displays the counts correctly.
I tried specifying the column names with a list, but that does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can change count to 'size', but the numbers don't add up the way you want. Is there a logic behind them or your result is from a bigger dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I hope I understood what you are after):

```
df['cnt'] = 1
dfPivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df,index=['Date'],columns=['Status'], values=['cnt'], aggfunc="count")
dfPivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
dfPivot

                             cnt                                   
Status     Awaiting Bank Account Credit Pulled Pre Credit Pull  Won
Date                                                               
2024-01-21                   0.0           1.0             0.0  1.0
2024-02-01                   0.0           1.0             0.0  0.0
2024-02-16                   0.0           1.0             0.0  0.0
2024-02-18                   0.0           1.0             0.0  0.0
2024-02-20                   1.0           3.0             1.0  1.0
```